# Calling AddDays on a Nullable DateTime object

Tags: c#, datetime

I had used `AddDays(x)` method before on `DateTime` objects and it was working fine but now my object is defined like this:

```
public DateTime? To_Date { get; set; }
```

And looks like this one does not have a `AddDays` method.  How can I call it then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `DateTime?` can be in a state representing `null`, you need to consider what to do if it's null.

The most obvious thing to do is to stay with a value of `null` (the day after `null` is `null`).

```
DateTime? later = ToDate.HasValue
  ? To_Date.Value.AddDays(numberOfDays)
  : (DateTime?)null;
```

It maybe that there's some meaningful default date you can use, in which case:

```
DateTime later = (ToDate ?? defaultDate).AddDays(numberOfDays);
```

This will use `defaultDate` when `ToDate` has no value, and the value of `ToDate` otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `To_Date.Value.AddDays(1);`

`To_Date` refers to the wrapper which only has a couple of properties. One is a flag to indicate whether or not it's null, the other is the value itself. First check that it's not null, try to use `AddDays` on the value.

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` if `To_Date` doesn't actually have that value.

Comment: @JonHanna "First check that it's not null". I explained how `Nullable<T>` works, I don't think a nullity check in my code sample is necessary. Good job copy-pasting my answer though!

Comment: If you're going to accuse me of plagiarism, I'm sure there's somewhere where my answer actually resembles another. In the meantime, since the OP isn't grokking why just calling `.AddDays()` isn't working, then they aren't considering the possibility of nullity, so it's worth pointing out, which my comment does.

Comment: @JonHanna oh yeah I can't find the place in my answer where I point that out and explain how `Nullable<T>` works...

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that does cover it fairly. You were totally justified in accusing me of plagiarism over the redundancy of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
To_Date.Value.AddDays(x);
```

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` if `To_Date` doesn't actually have that value.